# <p:command button with ajax not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following form used to refresh some data on the current page:

```
    <h:form id="refresh" rendered="#{sessionManager.loggedIn}">

      <p:commandButton  value="#{msg.refresh}" actionListener="#{findManager.refresh}" id="ui-refresh" icon="refresh"  
                        iconPos="left" inline="true" process="@this" 
                        update=":name,:refresh,:generalPropertiesEdit,:userAttributesEdit,:cableElements,:connectionDetails,:children" />

    </h:form>
```

and the refresh function looks like this:

```
public void refresh(){
  FindResult  node = ((FindResult)getSelectedNode().getData());
  Entity entity = ServerCache.instance(SessionManager.instance().getProject()).get( node.getId(), node.getEntity().getClass());
  node.setEntity(entity);
  node.generateProperties();

}
```

This seems to work just fine, but when I am testing it on an ipad it stops working. If I use ajax="false" then it works. 
I am using primefaces-mobile-0.9.2 and primefaces-3.2.

Thank you!

Comment: Ajax uses JavaScript. It thus won't work if JavaScript is disabled or unsupported. Have you verified and confirmed if your iPad supports JS and has it at least enabled and if so, that there are no JS-related errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is enabled and I am not getting any errors in the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by upgrading to primefaces-mobile-0.9.3 and primefaces-3.3.